# OpenLayers 3 bug when rendering GeoServer WFS layers?

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, wfs

I'm having issues rendering WFS layers with OpenLayers 3. If I follow the example [here](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/vector-wfs.html) and zoom out zoom out zoom out, my pc will soon freeze as the amount of data is huge. Don't even want to try on a phone.

If I set MaxFeatures to e.g. 500, the example works well. However I then alter the code to run with MY GeoServer, and I receive:

```
Assertion failed. See https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.4/doc/errors/#36 for details.
```

The text for error #36 is:

```
Unknown SRS type. Expected "name" or "EPSG"
```

My GeoServer is returning JSON as requested. I check the JSON sent from my GeoServer:

```
... "type": "FeatureCollection", "totalFeatures": 0,
    "features": [{"type": "Feature", "id": "plats.66", "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",…}, 
    ],
    "crs":{"type":"EPSG","properties":{"code":"3857"}}}
```

So, my GeoServer returns "type": "EPSG", however the OL WFS request parser seems to only accept "type":"name", this in spite of the error message.

My GeoServer is v2.5.3, the WFS request is v1.1.0 as per the OL example.

Is this a bug, if so is there a workaround?

Comment: Technically GeoJSON can only be in epsg:4326 now, you might want to use a better standard like GML if you need other projections.

Comment: If you just want to view data, why not use a WMS?

Comment: Yes, using a ol.format.GML and removing the outputFormat=application/json does enable this script to work. Thanks @Ian Turton